# Populate a multilevel TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview, multi-level

I try to populate a treeview with C#.
My data are:

```
level   data  
1       xxxx  
2       yyyy  
3       aaaa  
2       rrrr  
1       oooo
```

I would like something like :

```
xxxxx  
_yyyy  
__aaaa  
_rrrrr  
ooooo
```

I used some code like this :

```
 for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
 {
    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(dt.Rows[index]["Item"].ToString());
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
    for (int j = index; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
       TreeNode newNode1 = new TreeNode(dt.Rows[j]["Item"].ToString());
       newNode.Nodes.Add(newNode1);
       // treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode1);
    }
 }
```

But the result is a poor one. I can see only 2 levels.

I know that I need something like a recursive function, but I do not know how to go through the tree and come back to the root.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that:

```
void TraverseTree(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (var child in nodes)
    {
        DoSomethingWithNode(child);
        TraverseTree(child.Nodes);
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
TraverseTree(MyTreeView.Nodes);
```

Just replace `DoSomethingWithNode` method with your logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

Tor testing it assumes that you have the levels and the node Texts in the lines of a `Textbox`.

In the test button click I first create a `List<Tuple<int, string>>` to hold the levels and texts. Then I add a root node and fill the tree. Of course you can skip the root node and add a little extra logic to the `AddNodes` call..

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("ROOT");
    List <string> lines = textBox1.Lines.ToList();
    List<Tuple<int, string>> nodes = filleNodesList(lines);

    AddNodes(treeView1, treeView1.Nodes[0], nodes);
}
```

The `AddNodes` function is recursive; it removes the first entry after processing it and stop when the list is empty.

If you have level **jump up** an error is written to the output pane..

```
void AddNodes(TreeView tv, TreeNode cNode, List<Tuple<int, string>> nList)
{
    TreeNode nNode = new TreeNode();
    int nLevel = cNode.Level;
    Tuple<int, string> t = nList[0];
    // sibling: add to our parent!
    if (t.Item1 == nLevel) { nNode = cNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(t.Item2); }
    // next generation: our own child!
    else if (t.Item1 == nLevel + 1) { nNode = cNode.Nodes.Add(t.Item2); }
    // below us: seek down the line of parents!
    else if (t.Item1 < nLevel) {
        while (t.Item1 < cNode.Level) cNode = cNode.Parent;
        nNode = cNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(t.Item2); }
    // more than 1 above: error!
    else { Console.WriteLine("Error: node levels must not jump up: " + 
                              nLevel + " --> " + t.Item1); }
    // done with this element
    nList.RemoveAt(0);
    // anything left to do?
    if (nList.Count > 0) AddNodes(treeView1, nNode, nList);
}
```

The preparation assumes that the first string is a valid integer..:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>>  filleNodesList(List<string> lines)
{
    List<Tuple<int, string>>  nodes = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
    foreach(string s in lines)
    {
       string[] sl = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       Tuple<int, string> t = 
            new Tuple<int, string>(Convert.ToInt16(sl[0].Trim()), sl[1].Trim());
       nodes.Add(t);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```